# Dump Assembly Attributes in DebugDiag 2.0 Custom Rule

Tags: .net, custom-attributes, memory-dump, debugdiag, debug-diagnostic-tool

I am trying to create a custom dump analysis rule in [DebugDiag 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924).  Our code is a managed C# application with many assemblies.  Each assembly has its own custom attributes that contain revision information about the source files compiled to create the assembly.

I know it is possible to extract modules to a file via [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) commands `!savemodule` or !saveallmodules.  I can then use a tool like JetBrains DotPeek to inspect the assembly attributes.

I would like to find these attributes during a DebugDiag analysis and dump the attribute information to the DebugDiag report.  Having these attributes in the automated analysis report will help my team be more efficient.

How can I extract managed assembly attributes from a memory dump using DebugDiag 2.0 objects?

I have tried getting a module from the `NetDbgObj` debugger object, but I don't see a convenient way to get the attributes from there:

```
var module = debugger.GetModuleByModuleName("MyModule");
```

I can see ClrModule objects are avaialble via the NetDbgObj.ClrRuntime object.  I could get a ClrModule object, but I'm not sure what to do with that.  There are properties for `MetadataAddress`, `MetadataLength`, and `MetadataImport`, but I don't know what to do with those.

```
foreach (var module in debugger.ClrRuntime.EnumerateModules())
{
    object o = module.MetadataLength.MetadataImport;
    // now what?
}
```

These attribute objects are not on the managed heap, so `!dumpheap -type MyAttribute` does not return them.

The assembly attributes are stored as metadata somewhere in the assembly data.  I have seen the output of !DumpModule:

```
0:000> !DumpModule /d 0974f888
Name:       E:\MyProject\Output\Debug\MyAssembly.dll
Attributes: PEFile 
Assembly:   0be8f198
LoaderHeap:              00000000
TypeDefToMethodTableMap: 0119077c
TypeRefToMethodTableMap: 01190794
MethodDefToDescMap:      01190810
FieldDefToDescMap:       01190878
MemberRefToDescMap:      00000000
FileReferencesMap:       011908a8
AssemblyReferencesMap:   011908ac
MetaData start address:  08112e20 (5576 bytes)
```

I know I can dump the metadata using a command like dc:

```
0:000> dc 08112e20 L5576
08112e20  424a5342 00010001 00000000 0000000c  BSJB............
08112e30  302e3476 3330332e 00003931 00050000  v4.0.30319......
...lots of output...
```

I'n not sure where to go from here.